# Разве в Qt Creator нет утечки памяти? C++

Tags: c++, qt, утечка-памяти

Изучаю Qt и С++. Вижу, что все Qt-шные объекты, кнопочки и т.д. в QtCreator в коде создаются оператором new. Наподобии этого:

```
QChartView *cw = new QChartView(qchart);
```

При этом выделенная new память нигде не освобождается. Разве в C++ это не вызовет утечку памяти? Ведь когда выполнение кода выйдет за область видимости и *cw удалится, то выделенная new память останется и не освободится?

Comment: Вы указали родительский объект. При его удалении рекурсивно удаляются все дочерние.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html

Comment: Спасибо за документацию. Однако в гайдах и даже в примере от Qt по созданию круговой диаграммы есть строки: QPieSeries *ps = new QPieSeries(); Причем родитель не указывается ни в конструкторе, ни далее по коду. Что происходит с такими объектами? По документации я понял, что автоматическое удаление происходит именно при указании в конструкторе, либо через метод, родителя.

Comment: @CSharpLooser, методы некоторых объектов устанавливают родителя(`QLayout::addWidget`, например). В справке должно быть про захват владения(что то вроде`takes ownership`)

Answer (score 0):

Я сам когда только знакомился с Qt недоумевал с этого. Сейчас же я примерно понимаю почему это так: когда ты описываешь класс главного приложения и динамически выделяешь память для условной кнопки, то она по любому удалится при конце программы. Как по мне нет смысла удалять память этой кнопки в деструкторе
класса приложения потому что по идее это само приложение так сказать заберет память класса "из собой". Возможно есть более правильное и подробное объяснение, но пока мне свое пояснение кажется логичным.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).